# numpy generate reproducible random floats in a range

Tags: python, numpy

With numpy, how can I generate an array of random floats within a range?

Say I'd like to generate floats within 8 to 10. The seed is set

`eg = np.random.default_rng(567)`

how can I generate floats with eg?

Comment: What distribution do you want the randomly generated numbers to follow?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by setting a seed to an existing random number generator by calling `np.random.seed(567)` **each time** you want to restart the sequence.

If you'd like to create a new Generator, you can do it as in your question:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=567)
```

Then, you can sample random numbers just by calling  `uniform` method which takes `min`, `max` and `size` parameters.  In your case:

```
size = (3, 4)
rng.uniform(8, 10, size)
```

will return an array with 3 row and 4 columns that consists of floats between 8 and 10.  Apart from uniform distribution there are many more predefined ones that are accessible the same way as `uniform` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#distributions).

You can also do it with `random` that also can take an argument of `size`. In your case:

```
rng.random(size) * 2 + 8
```

will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

`np.random.random()` generates floats between 0 and 1.  So, multiply by 2 and add 8.

```
def make_8_10():
    return np.random.random() * 2 + 8
```